# RC time constant - theory vs practice (simulation)

Tags: capacitor, resistors, delay

Time constant formula is

```
T = R * C
```

I need to create a delay of about 10ms so with a resistance of 3300 ohms I calculate that I'd need about 3.3uF capacitance in order to achieve that.

I [simulated this circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+0.575460267600573+45+5+43%0Av+80+64+160+64+0+0+40+3.3+0+0+0.5%0Av+224+32+288+32+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+224+32+224+48+0%0Ag+80+64+80+80+0%0At+368+128+400+128+0+1+0+0+100%0Aw+400+144+400+176+0%0Ag+400+176+400+208+0%0Ar+208+128+272+128+0+3300%0Ac+272+128+272+192+0+0.0000032999999999999997+0.001%0Ag+272+192+272+224+0%0Aw+272+128+368+128+0%0Aw+208+128+208+320+0%0Ar+208+320+272+320+0+330%0A162+272+320+368+320+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Ag+368+320+368+352+0%0Aw+160+128+208+128+0%0As+160+64+160+128+0+0+false%0A162+400+48+400+80+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Ar+288+32+352+32+0+330%0Aw+352+32+400+32+0%0Aw+400+32+400+48+0%0Aw+400+80+400+112+0%0A) to find out that I'm only creating a delay of about 3ms. Why is that difference?

[image]

Comment: What are those round blips? What's the white thing in the upper left quadrant? What are the voltage sources?

Comment: I provided a link to the simulation: round blips - LEDs, white thing - switch, voltages - 3.3v signal and 5v source (controlled)

Comment: If someone has to follow an external link to understand a question it is not complete. Can't you use the integrated schematic design tool that's meant to do exactly this?

Comment: php_nub_qq....It seems that you did not take into account the input resistance at the base of the transistor. This resistance appears in parallel to the 3.3kohm resistor.

Comment: Also, please use component designators, R1, R2, LED1, LED2, etc.. so that we can discuss the circuit.

Comment: Theory and practice are not at odds here. The time constant is the time taken for an exponential to rise to 63% of its final value. The value of the voltage at the time constant may, or may not, be what you require to perform some switching operation - that's for you to decide. There's nothing magical about the time constant, it's only a measure of an exponential's speed of response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have calculated is the time constant of the R-C network

$$\tau = R\cdot C = 3300\cdot3.3\mu = 10.89ms$$

From a voltage source of 3.3V, this is the time for the voltage across the capacitor to reach ~63% ~ 2.2V.

The problem is, what is loading the R-C is the B-E of the BJT. Ideal-case (ignoring leakage), your circuit looks like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1OHTHm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Once the voltage across the capacitor reaches ~0.6V, the B-E of the BJT is forward biased and the circuit looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJa3RYm.png)</sup>

So, the real question is, how long until that R-C network forward bias's the BJT?

$$ t = -ln(\frac{V-V_c}{V})\cdot R \cdot C $$
This comes out at roughly 2.19ms

Comment: This model assumes that the circuit (it is non-linear !!) would behave like an exponential function with a simple R*C product. But this is not true!. For my opinion, the classical definition for a time constant must not be applied because of the strong non-linear influence of the B-E pn junction.

Comment: I agree, but as a 1st pass approximation as to why there is a massive difference between the expected time and the simulated time, it is good enough. Basically the characteristics of the load was not considered. This could further be expanded upon to include Vbe characteristics to hone in on the exact time. Honestly if a "precise time" is needed then some form of schmitt or timer is required

Comment: From my experience I noticed it's nearly impossible to get a predictable result without a smitt trigger in serie with the RC circuit.

Comment: I also make use of a second resistor between after the capacitor. I'm not sure of the effect of it but it may help.

Answer (score 2):

An RC circuit generates a T=RC delay to a threshold of (1-e)/e, or about 0.63 of the original step. If you trigger at a different threshod, you will get a different delay.

Your threshold appears to be the 0.7 V Vbe of a silicon BJT. If the battery voltage is much higher than 1.1 V, perhaps 3 or 5 V, then the delay to 0.7 V will be much less than RC.